# How to show convert current date in format "yyyy-mm-dd" to english format e.g. "Jan 28"

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting date in format "*yyyy-mm-dd*" `NSString` like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

How do I convert this string to display in format like "*Jan 18*", only first three literals of month and day, no year? I know its a query specific question but really banging my head over it?

Comment: Did search of what you can put in dateFormat? DateFormatter works both way. From NSString to NSDate and NSDate to NSString. So after you have the date, you can change the format and change it into a NSString with the format you want. I don't understand what you want to do with your code. Doesn't accord with your goal.

Comment: I just wanted to know the date format to use. Below answer gives me the correct format! Its easy to downvote a question. I guess tough to answer one!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM dd";
NSString *dateString2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

That should get you two different strings in the two different formats.  If you have the string and have to absolutely go from it to another string in a different format then:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDateString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd";
NSString *dateString2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

It's almost the same code for both iterations.

Comment: Thanks I didn't mean to know about switching from NSString to NSDate and vice versa.. just wanted to know the DateFormat that shall display date in english literals. It works great. Thanks!